# Fatal error in sugarCRM  view page for custom module 

Tags: sugarcrm

I am new to sugarCRM, I had created a custom module using module builder. Everything was working fine till yesterday, all of a sudden I get this error when I try to open my module

```
Call to a member function setup() on a non-object in xxx\xxx\xxx\include\MVC\Controller\ControllerFactory.php on line 78
```

I tried to search for the solution but couldnt find any .

Can anybody tell me what went wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a controller.php file defined for your custom module? If so, I'm guessing the permissions on that file are incorrect.

Comment: I have a controller file but nothing is written on that file, it is blank

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message in my custom module with a custom extende controller.
I named the controller class CustomMyModuleName. But it should be named CustomMyoduleName**Controller**